# How to explicitly re-run an analyzer for whole solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

Imagine an analyzer that is part of a Visual Studio extension. Output of the analyzer depends on some options that are accessible to user via custom options page e.g.: Tools/Options.../My Extension/Analyzer feature1 enabled.

Is there a way how to re-run the analyzer for whole solution after the option is changed?